# Python Dictionary Username and Password

Tags: python, if-statement, user-interface, passwords

My code is working how I want it to work. The only thing that I want to add, but I don't know how to do it, is that The user should only get five tries to enter the password when he enters the incorrect password, after which point the program should tell them that they are kicked off of the system. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
    def main():
       username_password = {"Maria":"hola",
                        "Victoria":"bye"} 
       login_username = str(input("Please enter your username.\n")) 
       login_password = str(input("Please enter your password.\n"))  
       login_username, login_password = login_username.strip(), login_password.strip() 
      if login_username in username_password and login_password == 
    username_password[login_username]: 
           print("Logged in")  
       else: 
          print("incorrect username / password, please try again")
    
    
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a while or for loop. If they get the right username and password, it would break out of the loop. If it is wrong, it would continue and ask them them the username and password while also printing the error statement. Try the following:

```
def main():
    tries = 0
    username_password = {"Maria":"hola",
                    "Victoria":"bye"} 
    while tries < 5:
        login_username = str(input("Please enter your username.\n")) 
        login_password = str(input("Please enter your password.\n"))  
        login_username, login_password = login_username.strip(), login_password.strip() 
        if login_username in username_password and login_password == username_password[login_username]: 
           print("Logged in")
           break
        else: 
          print("incorrect username / password, please try again")
          tries += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

that thing is not hard to be honest just make a for loop like this

```
def main():
   username_password = {"Maria":"hola","Victoria":"bye"}
   for x in range(5):
   login_username = input("Please enter your username.\n")
   login_password = input("Please enter your password.\n") 
   login_username, login_password = login_username.strip(), login_password.strip() 
  if login_username in username_password and login_password == 
username_password[login_username]: 
       print("Logged in")  
   else: 
      print("incorrect username / password, please try again")
      # you can write here print('try again)


main()
```

to tell you something first value is a key so if you made if something in (name of dictionary) it will search between keys not values if you want it to search between values write dictionary.values()
login_username = input("Please enter your username.\n")